# Getting out of DLL Hell with Microsoft.VC90.CRT?

Tags: dll, com, assemblies, py2exe, winsxs

I've built a inproc com server dll which I can package as 1 file or many via the build utility py2exe.  When I allow all the dependencies to remain external, I have no issues, but bundling as 1 file produces problems.

When the dll is utilized (either registering it or instantiating a com object from it), it immediately loads `MSVCR90.DLL` from the path `c:\windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6871_none_50944e7cbcb706e5\MSVCR90.DLL` no matter what I do, I can't change that.  There is no information that I can find (using Dependency Walker) to indicate what is causing that to load.  It just happens magically...

Then, later on it loads that dll again via an explicit call to `LoadLibraryA("MSVCR90.dll")` (part of some py2exe black box?), but this time it does not look into the `winsxs` manifests / directory.  Instead it looks to the system path and/or will respect a dll redirection.  That's when the problem occurs.  If I set the system path to start with `c:\windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt...\` it will load the exact same dll and be happy - but if ANY other file is utilized - inclusive of a copy of the EXACT same dll - but at a different path - then the whole thing blows up.  It can't handle using two different files.

How can I fix this?  Ideally, I've love to make the initial magic loading of the dll draw upon a private assembly, but no matter what I do with manifests or .dll.local etc it will not respect that until this second dll loading takes place.

Note that with the non-bundled dll (external dependencies) it always uses the winsxs MSVCR90.DLL.

I can "fix" my failure to use the dll by forcing the system path to load the winsxs copy, but that is pretty useless for a deployable com server!

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you DLL has a manifest that tells the module loader to search also in the SxS storage.

You have several choices

1. Build your DLL using static linkage. Not using any of the MFC-DLLs (see project settings)
2. Don't use a side by side manifest for the DLL and still use the MFC DLLs. But beware you have to ship those DLL with your DLL in the local path (see DLL search sequence docs)
3. Use a later build of VS. Later versions of VS don't use the SxS storage any more and there are no manifests for those DLLs any more.

For the 2. see this article in [code project](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19155/Create-projects-easily-with-private-MFC-ATL-and-CR). There is an update for VS-2008 [here].
[2](http://blog.m-ri.de/index.php/2008/05/06/hotfix-fuer-usemsprivateassembliesh-und-vc-2008/)

Build your DLL

Comment: Thanks, but I think the premise of all this is based on the assumption I'm writing VC++ in Visual Studio.  I'm not.  I'm written the code in Python, and used py2exe magic to create the dll.  I have choice for static for dynamic linking etc other than by trying to pull apart and recompile the underlying tools.

Comment: That said, what specifically in the manifest tells the loader use to SxS?  I've tweaked the manifest 100 times trying to get his to work (though I'm not sure if it's even being respected for sure...).  I had luck using a .dll.local to redirect, but as a wrote in the original question that is only respected on a subsequent call to LoadLibrary after some mystery process loads the dll initially.

Comment: To answer my question about SxS, that's the job of the publicKeyToken.  In theory, removing that from the manifests directs the use of private assemblies.  I had already tried that, but I tried again.  That has no impact for me.  I can load the private assembly - but only upon the "second" loading of the dll.  The first one remains the SxS. I think it's wrapped up in the pythoncom and/or py2exe dll loader code and embedded dlls.  I'm guessing the solution requires a deep dive into that source... (Which I've already begun, but without success)